# Neo4j loop thru nodes to improve query performance

Tags: performance, loops, neo4j, cypher

I'm working on a project on Neo4j. I have about 1 million nodes and 4 million relationships.

When I try to perform a query, it takes like 15 seconds to give me the result. I also have set indexes on email.createdAt

The query is as follows:

```
MATCH (email:Email) 
WITH email 
ORDER BY email.createdAt 
WHERE email.body CONTAINS "word" 
RETURN email 
SKIP 0 
LIMIT 10
```

So, I'm trying to figure out how can I improve the sintaxis and the time it takes to give the result.

So far I have an idea, but I don't know if its possible.

I think the query must be like this:

- Bring all the emails ordered by date DESC
- Loop thru each one of the email nodes (desc) searching for the "word" in the email.body
- When it gets 10 matches, it stops and returns only those 10 emails.

The main idea is not to loop thru all of the nodes, but only the neccesary to find the first 10 matches. Maybe using Unwind, For Each, I don't know.

Does anybody have an idea on how to write this query? Thank you guys!

Comment: add an index on email.body

Comment: I have a procedure in apoc that does that, currently only for ASC, in 3.5 hopefully for desc too.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, you should make your query as short and simple as you can. The Neo4j Cypher planner is REALLY powerful, and by trying to micro manage it, you hinder it from using the best plan.

In your case, the start `Match (email:Email) With email` basically forces the planner to load all email nodes (because WITH creates a logical partition in the cypher), and the planner can't really optimize at that point because you've already locked it into the worst performance (as it is only filtering from there).

A better Cypher would look like this

```
Match (email:Email) 
Where email.body Contains "word" 
Return email Order by email.createdAt Skip 0 Limit 10
```

Basically the same, but without the micromanaging WITH part. The WHERE is the only part that changes what nodes are loaded, so by doing it like this, the planner can stop after it finds 10 nodes that match the criteria when scanning the `createdAt` index.

In general, unless you want to become a Neo4j DB expert, the best cypher is usually the simplest one you can write, with indexes on key fields.